# Discord.js Reactionroles on VPS not working

Tags: discord, discord.js, vps

So i'm working on a small Discord bot for fun and on my Windows machine everything is working, but trying it on a VPS doesn't work

Heres my code

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "ReactionRole",
    describtion: "Will create a reaction role embed",
    async execute(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.author.id !== "465838976410976276") return;
        const channel = "860160937725788170";

        const placeholder = ""

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("Reaction Roles")
            .setDescription("React to an Emoji to get the Role u desire\n\n"
                    + `${placeholder } for a role`)
            

        const messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        messageEmbed.react(placeholder );
       

        client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (message.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === placeholder ) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add("894699397676429333");
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        })

        client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (message.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === placeholder ) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove("894699397676429333");
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

My OS is `Debian 10`

[image: My Error]

I tried to change the emojis to different kinds like Unicode but nothing worked.

Comment: The emoji is being replace with the string `??`. Make sure the source code on your VPS is correct.

Comment: In the messageEmbed its working but not as a reaction. The reaction throws an Error

Comment: Regardless, you can see in the url that it's trying to send `??/@me` which I assume means it's try to use the `??` reaction which doesn't exist. Something along the way is wrong (node version? discord.js version? etc). May involve printing some stuff out in Discord.js along the way.

Comment: I i also guessed that so i wiped my VPS and installed everything new. i tried changing the emojis using unicode etc. everything. But this only happens on my  server. And i cant figure out why it doesnt find these emojis. I tried just logging the emojis but even that doesnt work

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1057 Related?